# Will encryption of /home partition create problems if I do a new install in the future while saving /home?

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning, encryption, home-directory

I have a dual boot Windows/Linux machine that I am doing a full revamp of. After saving my personal files, I wiped the 1 TB drive and did a clean install of Windows 10. I have reduced the Windows partition to 120 GB and now I want to add a 80 GB /root partition for Linux and a /home partition with all the remaining space (plus a 4 GB swap partition). If I encrypt the /home partition during install, will I still be able to access the files in it if in the future I do a new install of Ubuntu (or if I try another distro like Mint, Peppermint, Elementary, etc.) and re-adopt the /home partition? Or is it safer in this scenario to not encrypt /home? Are there any special steps I need to take to re-access the encrypted /home if I install a new distro in the future?

Comment: Encrypt just your own user's home folder? Or an entire partition? I think the Ubuntu installer can do either/both, but the whole partition may be the root/system  partition

Answer (score 1):

Yes you will be able to access to your data of course.

There are many way of doing that and I am going to suggest you 2 here.

1) You decrypt your home partition before re-installation and you can do this by using the following command:

```
 #ecryptfs-setup-private --undo
```

Here is the step by step about how to remove the decryption from your home.

```
  http://rayslinux.blogspot.ie/2011/01/caught-out-by-being-overzealous-remove.html
```

I tried myself and it worked for me.

2) You can install your system and choose /home partition the existing one by de-selecting to format the partition and that will basically take it as your /home, but you will still need to access to it as it is encrypted.

```
   #ecryptfs-unwrap-passphrase
   #ecryptfs-recover-private
```

are the 2 main tools that you will work with. You can find different how-to's about this but here is the step by step one:

```
   http://www.howtogeek.com/116297/how-to-recover-an-encrypted-home-directory-on-ubuntu/
```

There are many other ways to do that but the easier way would be of course to remove the encyrption before re-installation.

Comment: From the Q it's not clear, but it sounds like the OP might be asking about a whole dm-crypt/LUKS encrypted home partition. But, I don't think the Ubuntu installer does that easily, I think it does use eCryptFS to encrypt just individual homes.

Comment: Hey Xen2050, I guess I was actually thinking about the whole /home partition but not for any real reason. An encrypted home folder with the partition is all I really need and that makes sense to me now that I think about it more. I will try one of ostendali's methods.